# Add QR Code reader to Shopify iOS POS app?

Tags: shopify, qr-code, pos

I'd like to add a QR Code reader to the Shopify iOS POS app so that the employee can scan a QR Code based loyalty card during checkout.

Is this possible?

If the QR Code reader can't be added to the app (using the iPad camera); can one do the same thing using a handheld scanner (using an app embedded in the POS app)?

Comment: Does the Shopify iOS POS app provides APIs for related programming?

Comment: @Rachel Shopify iOS POS app provides the means for merchants to embed web apps within the POS app.

Comment: You can try out this [online demo of scanning barcode from mobile camera in a web app](https://demo.dynamsoft.com/DBR_Mobile/ScanQRToMobileBarcodeReader.aspx) and see if it meets your needs. The demo is created using a 3rd party barcode reader SDK.